# Про-дивизион. Как пишется?

Tags: выбор-слов, заимствования

*Про-дивизион* (в спорте) как пишется, — слитно или через дефис?

Answer (score 1):

**Дивизион** может обозначать  систему иерархии в спорте, например в футболе:   http://alvin-almazov.ru/soccer-rus/divizion/

Слово ***продивизион*** мне не встречалось, но приставка ПРО в этом случае, возможно, имеет такое же значение, как в словах ***проректор*** (заместитель ректора) и ***прогимназия*** (от лат. ***pro*** — перед и гимназия).

Написание слитное.

Comment: Уверен, что здесь имеется в виду профессиональный дивизион (в отличие от университетского, например), поэтому приставка не может иметь такое значение.

Comment: _приставка ПРО_ Здесь PRO — это сокращение от **professional**, что означает профессиональный, то есть профессиональный дивизион или лига. Ср., для примера, AM — любительский (от английского **amateur**) дивизион.

Comment: _Дивизион — это система иерархии в футболе._ Не обязательно "в футболе" и не обязательно "иерархии". Деление может быть по регионам (например, европейский дивизион) и по другим признакам.

Comment: если писать pro-дивизион, то именно так?

Comment: Дефисное написания приставок ПРО или PRO не встречается в русском языке. О значении слова не могу сказать ничего определенного, нужно знать, в каком тексте оно употреблено. Профессиональный дивизион писался бы как профдивизион.

Comment: Ответ исправлен  с учетом замечаний.